# findViewById from viewpager

Tags: android

Hello im trying to use viewpager.

My problem is that I can't find views from my sliding views, I get NPE.

This is my code for finiding views:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    focusedView = mPager.getChildAt(arg0);

    button = (ImageButton) focusedView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

I get NPE on this line:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

All of my views sliding views have a button with "button" id.

I also tried this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    button = (ImageButton) mPager.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

I got here NPE too.

How can I find views from views inside pageviewer?

Comment: Can you post the LogCat entry when the error occors, please? =)

Comment: Childs are `Fragments` or `Activities`?

Comment: Show us your XML too, please.

Comment: Just as a side note, why are you keeping `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` when you have already implemented your method? Such comment is there to remind you that such method was generated and needs your attention to implement it.

Comment: The whole code i ts long i just gave here an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the click events inside the fragments instead, you can do it in the method `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` for example.

Comment: I made its with inner class and its working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this code in an activity or fragment.

Declare a `final` variable for your button on activity or fragment, get the reference to it in `onCreate` or `onResume` and then you will be able to use it in `onPageSelected`.

Sample (not complete) code:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private final Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

         button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    }


    // view pager
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

        focusedView = mPager.getChildAt(arg0);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

}
```